# VBA Excel Charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am novice in VBA Excel and I have a column chart with multiple columns. I want to be able to set a column's color depending on it's value. At the moment I can select my `Chart object` and the `SeriesCollection`, in addition, I can see what values each column has. This is my code:

```
Sub changeChartColumnColor()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim mySrs As Series
Dim myPts As Points
Dim x As Variant

For Each ChtObj In Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").ChartObjects
    If ChtObj.Name = "My Chart" Then
        For Each mySrs In ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
            For Each x In mySrs.Values
                MsgBox x
            Next x
        Next mySrs
    End If
Next ChtObj

End Sub
```

I tried looking it up in internet and on this website but I am not able to find any relevant information. Please note that I know how to change the color for the whole `SeriesCollection` (`mySrs.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)`).

My problem is: How to change the color of each of the series' columns?

Thank you!

Comment: Recording a macro and changing the color of the series columns would generate the needed code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Google -> "how to record a macro in excel", record the macro, and change the color of the series manually. The recorded macro will show you the code.

Comment: How is this going to support the ranges? I am trying to avoid changing the color manually for 30 columns to support multiple ranges.

Comment: Just give it a try & see the generated code.

Comment: @UnitaChawhan Recording the macro for 1 column change will tell you what the correct SeriesCollection properties to change are.  You can then plug that into your macro

Comment: Check out my tutorial [VBA Conditional Formatting of Charts by Value](https://peltiertech.com/vba-conditional-formatting-of-charts-by-value/).